# Test Kotlin lambda within "use" standard library function

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, lambda, mockito

I am trying to unit test code within a lambda function that is passed into the use Kotlin standard library inline function. I tried using thenAnswer with mockito but couldn't get the code to compile with the isA() or any() ArgumentMatchers from the [Mockito-Kotlin](https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin) library. Here are the code snippets:

**Code Under Test**

```
sessionFactory.openSession().use { session ->
    // Code I want to test
}
```

**Unit Test Code**

```
val sessionFactory: SessionFactory = mock()
val session: Session = mock()
whenever(sessionFactory.openSession()).thenReturn(session)
whenever(session.use(isA())).thenAnswer{
    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    (it.arguments[0] as (Any) -> Any).invoke(session)
}
```

Am I on the right track? One workaround is to not use the use function and explicitly close the Hibernate session object in a finally block, but I'd like to not have to do that.

Answer (score 1):

It's getting less painful if you test your code directly, without the `openSession().use`

Production Code:

```
    sessionFactory.openSession().use { session ->
        codeIwantToTest(session)
    }
}

// visible for testing
fun codeIwantToTest(session: Session) {
    // your code goes here
}
```

Test Code:

```
private val session: Session = mock()

@Test
fun `some test`() {
    // some set up

    codeIwantToTest(session)

    // asserts and verify(session)
}
```

In the case you doubt that `use` does its job, test it like so (but its definitely kind of paranoia)

```
@Test
fun `test library function use`() {
    session.use { session ->
        session.beginTransaction()
    }

    verify(session).beginTransaction()
    verify(session).close()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response Frank Neblung. It turns out I was jumping ahead to stubbing out the "use" function before running the method under test without it. If you take out the stub, the "use" function executes fine with the mock.